# Getting HTTP request from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, http, screen-scraping

Is there a way to access the http request IE made when the page is already loaded. For instance, I have an application that is opening a browser window. I want to scrape the page, but would like to get the entire http request for that page (not just the URL).

I have downloaded the developer tools, but don't see anything in there for the request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a great utility called "[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)" that you can use.

It is a web debugging proxy, so it'll act as a go-between for all your web requests.

It's an awesome utility and has helped me many times with things like this.

Comment: Fiddler and similar tools are the only real option here.  IE itself doesn't hang onto the request once the response is received.  IE8 has great new dev tools, but doesn't include a network debugger; use Fiddler for that.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [ieHTTPHeaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html) in the past and it works great.  It's an IE addon.